# startActivityForResult and setResult with RESULT_OK does not work

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, but if I do the following in `OneActivity` to launch `TwoActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

And in `TwoActivity` when I pass back to `OneActivity`:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(SOURCE, TAG);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

finish();
```

With the above code and after overriding `onActivityResult` in `OneActivity` nothing happens. `onActivityResult` doesn't even seem to be called. If, however, I change `RESULT_OK` to `0`, it works.

Is this expected? Has anyone else experienced that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the docs definition of the [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method. It says:

> requestCode   int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

So your request code should be >= 0. If you check the value of the [RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) response code, it's -1. It's important to note that the request code isn't the same as the result code. The request code serves you to identify the request the result is for, and the result code tells you if the request was successful or not.

Comment: Duh, what a silly mistake on my part! That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @tvalent2 No problem, glad to help you =).

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two different concepts:

- The `requestCode` (the second parameter to `startActivityForResult`) is a unique ID you assign that can be any positive integer.
- The `resultCode` (the first parameter to `setResult`) must be one of the constants in the Activity class as seen in the [setResult documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent))

You'll note that your `onActivityResult` receives both the `requestCode` you pass into `startActivityForResult` **and** the `resultCode` that you've set in `setResult` - make sure you are comparing the right numbers in your `onActivityResult`

Comment: Wow, what a mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please check your code with this sample:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    TextView textView1;  
    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    }  
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }  
}
```

and then SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  
    EditText editText1;  
    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  
        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    String message=editText1.getText().toString();  
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity  
                }  
            });  
    }
```